# How to auto generate d.ts file for a variable in a .ts file?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-types, typescript-declarations

In this repo I have manually created [pluginApi.d.ts](https://github.com/stashapp/stash/blob/develop/ui/v2.5/src/pluginApi.d.ts) from [pluginApi.tsx](https://github.com/stashapp/stash/blob/develop/ui/v2.5/src/pluginApi.tsx). As the web ui exposes some useful functions through `window.PluginApi` variable. And I want plugin devs to get code suggestion where they just download this `pluginApi.d.ts` file and put it in their `project/src/types` folder. As I did this manually I can't port all the nested types, like sometimes if the types are very big then I just use `:any`.